# Sitecore Powershell Extensions - Remote Update Package installation not working after recycling app pool

Tags: powershell-extensions, update-packages

I'm trying to run an update package installation remotely by using the Remoting PowerShell module for SPE. It doesn't install it unless I run it on the SPE console first, and then, remote installations work correctly. Once the app pool is restarted it starts failing again.

**This is the script**

```
$SitecoreInstanceUri = "http://sitecoreinstanceurl"
$SitecorePackagePath = "C:\packages\mypackage.update"

#Create a new script session
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username remoteuser -Password b -ConnectionUri $SitecoreInstanceUri

Write-Host "Installing Sitecore update package '$SitecorePackagePath' on '$SitecoreInstanceUri'"

#Invoke the script, actually start installing the package
$jobId = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    $package = $using:SitecorePackagePath
    Write-Log "Installing Sitecore update package '$package'"
    Install-UpdatePackage -Path $package -UpgradeAction Upgrade -InstallMode Install
} -AsJob -Verbose

#Double check if a jobId was created. If we don't have an id, something is wrong
if (!$jobId) { 
    Write-Host "No jobId was created. Please check if your Powershell Remoting is activated on the target instance '$SitecoreInstanceUri'"
}

#Poll every 5 seconds and check if the script has completed
Wait-RemoteScriptSession -Session $session -Id $jobId -Delay 5 -Verbose

Write-Host "Sitecore update package installed."
Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

**This is the output**

```
Installing Sitecore update package 'C:\packages\mypackage.update' on 'http://sitecoreinstance'

VERBOSE: Checking the Runspace for the variable SitecorePackagePath.
VERBOSE: Checking the Runspace for the variable id.
VERBOSE: Polling job 2078e99e-99b7-4e4c-924c-96f1d84e2727. Status : Available.
VERBOSE: Finished polling job 2078e99e-99b7-4e4c-924c-96f1d84e2727.
VERBOSE: Checking the Runspace for the variable id.
Sitecore update package installed.
```

On a successful remote installation, it shows lots of lines with the status as Busy, before showing it as Available and finishing the job.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Is it failing because you are updating files? What failure message do you see?

Comment: The package contains Sitecore items only, and I don't see any error message, nor in the console or logs.

Comment: How do you know it's failing?

Comment: it's not installing it, I don't see any change and the script finishes almost immediately, but when it's a good installation it takes about 4 mins to complete.

Comment: Have you tried with a small package of 1-2 items to see if it works as expected?

Comment: Just tried, but I get the same result

Comment: I tried on my local machine pointing to a local Sitecore instance, and also on dev environment, both with the same result. BTW, I'm working with Sitecore 9.0.2 and SPE 4.7.2